# Error when trying to update the table in IBM DB2 using Merge

Tags: merge, db2, mainframe, db2-zos

I have a SQL statement which I am trying to execute from a console application on IBM DB2 database.

```
MERGE INTO Table 1 AS A 
USING Table 2 AS B 
ON A.IDTEXT = B.IDTEXT AND A.STATE = 1 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET A.STATE = 5
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR [42601] [IBM][SQLDS/VSE] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "MERGE" was found following "MERGE".  Expected tokens may include:  "MERGE".
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: According to the "Db2 for VSE & VM SQL Reference" for V7 release 5, this product does not support the MERGE statement. You will need to recode .

Comment: The tag indicates z/os but the message is VSE.  Are you calling a Db2 instance from VSE that resides on z/OS ?

Comment: @Hogstrom I tagged the question with "db2-zos" (possibly erroneously, but I thought it was close enough) since there isn't a VSE specific tag. Please feel free to remove the tag if you feel it's misleading.

Comment: No worries on the tag.  I was asking as each platform has more or less functionality.  So this is VSE.   Ok, I’m doing some research